# Woocommerce Add Customizable Product to Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a customizable product to the woocommerce cart.

I have all details calculated and ready to be able to add it to the cart.

Looking into the woocommerce api, it looks like I can use REST, but I'm just thinking there must be an easier way with regular php.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
function add_product_to_wc(){
                                        global $woocommerce;

                                        $product_id = $name;
                                        $variationid = $type;
                                        $spec = array();
                                        $spec['Dimension'] = $dimension; //user select Dimension
                                        $spec['ColorOne'] = $colorOne; //user select color 1
                                        $spec['ColorTwo'] = $colorTwo; //user select color 2

                                        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $variationid, $spec, null );}
```

Am I totally off ? or how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me - inserted in functions.php and the reference to this function via a html form:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'customcart');


function customcart() {

  if (isset($_POST["addcustomcarts"])) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => $_POST["textInput"],
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     =>'product'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    if ( $product_ID ){
      wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, 'design-selv-skilte', 'product_cat' );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', 100 );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', 100 );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock' );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_sku', 'designselvskilt' );    
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_visibility', 'hidden' );
      //wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, 'tekst på mit skilt', text1, False );

      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );

      exit( wp_redirect( '/kurv' )  );

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [`add_to_cart()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#844-958) method available on the `WC_Cart` object. Your example is mostly correct, however you would need to provide the numeric `$product_id` and `$variation_id`.

It is also preferable to access the WooCommerce object using `WC()` rather than the `global $woocommerce`.

```
$product_id = 123; // use the real product ID
$variation_id = 456; // use the real variation ID
$dimension = 'Large';
$colorOne = 'Color One';
$colorTwo = 'Color Two';

WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 
    $product_id, 
    $variation_id, 
    array( 'Dimension'=>$dimension, 'ColorOne'=>$colorOne, 'ColorTwo'=>$colorTwo ), 
    null 
);
```

Comment: but what if the product is customizable product that is created via a customizer - so there is not product ID beforehand. Should I then create the product in the same instance ?

Comment: There is always a product ID, you have to create the variable product first in WooCommerce. You could do it programmatically as well, but it would still need to be created first so you can use the ID to add it to your cart.